# Unexpected behavior :: "batch_size" parameter for WriteToBigQuery PTransform (Python 3.7, Apache Beam)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

For my Streaming pipeline  I'm seeing some un-expected behavior when using `batch_size` parameter for PTransform `apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery`? (source is Cloud Pub/Sub, sink is BigQuery table, tried both on DirectRunner and DataFlowRunner, Python 3.7, apache-beam v2.15.0)

The [comments](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7abf88cbd5a30327ef333c5b4eedfc2eb84d739b/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L913) in the code says:

> batch_size (int): Number of rows to be written to BQ per streaming API insert. The default is 500.

In my pipeline code, I had set value to 100 in my PTransform (default value is 500)

```py
pipeline | "read_sub" >> beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=SUB)
    | "extract_message" >> beam.Map(lambda m : json.loads(m.data)) \
    | "convert_bq_format" >> beam.Map(lambda m : {"message" : str(m)}) \
    | "write" >> bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(batch_size=100, project=PROJECT, dataset=BQ_DATASET, table=BQ_TABLE)
```

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR** as per my interpretation [correct me if i'm mistaken in my interpretation]:

- nothing should be written to BQ table until 100 elements published to pub/sub
- no Streaming API method `tabledata.insertAll` will be consumed from the project's API Quota 
  even checked the [code here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7abf88cbd5a30327ef333c5b4eedfc2eb84d739b/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L824) for `process()` function of BigQueryWriteFn which is called by WriteToBigQuery PTransform and believe my interpretation of this parameter makes sense (nothing flushed

**ACTUAL BEHAVIOR** that I'm seeing is after publishing just 10 elements to the pub/sub topic:

- each of those elements are successfully streamed to BigQuery table with-in seconds
- From Project's API quota, the pipeline also consumed 3 requests to streaming method bigquery.tabledata.insertAll (I'd still expect 1, considering only 1 streaming api could be used to stream just 10 messages with `batch_size =100`

Can someone clarify pls. why i'm seeing this unexpected behavior? or, is there something that I mis-understood how this parameter settings behave?

Comment: What happens if you send 100 elements from Pub/Sub? The behavior is expected?

Comment: The bundle sent to your worker might be smaller than 100 elements and as such the method `finish_bundle()` gets called earlier than you expected (see [line 831](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7abf88cbd5a30327ef333c5b4eedfc2eb84d739b/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L831)) - maybe it's worth playing around with bundle sizes?

Just wanted to point out as well that it looks like that parameter (`batch_size`) gets assigned to `_max_batch_size` on [line 723](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7abf88cbd5a30327ef333c5b4eedfc2eb84d739b/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L723)